# Can Jenkins monitor cron jobs that I run using crontab?

Tags: cron, jenkins

I have written some cron jobs using the crontab feature on my ubuntu. Can I use Jenkins to monitor these jobs?

Edit 1: I have Jenkins already installed on my local machine: localhost:8080. So right now, I have cronjobs running on crontab. I cannot create a new job on Jenkins and run them on Jenkins's shell because of certain requirements.
Following Pragmatic's solution, I looked at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs and tried to sudo apt-get install jenkins-external-tool-monitor, but I am getting: E: Couldn't find package jenkins-external-tool-monitor. Any work arounds?

Edit 2: I have figured it out. Very Important: I tried to set this up using jenkins-core-1.47*.jar file, and it didnt work. It did work with jenkins-core-1.466.jar. So if you are using some .jar file, stop jenkins, replace it with a jenkins.war that corresponds to jenkins-core-1.466.jar and start jenkins after. That should work!

Comment: If you figured it out, [why not create an answer?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that!!

Have a look at this link: [Monitoring external jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs).

I could have explained the whole method here itself but the details in the question were minimal.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So I am trying to follow these steps and when I tried sudo apt-get install jenkins-external-tool-monitor, E: Couldn't find package jenkins-external-tool-monitor. Is there any other place I can find an installation of this? And is this necessary for me to use Jenkins to monitor my cron jobs? I assume that it is?

Comment: were you able to fix your issue? i can see your another comment posted after this.
If yes, please mark the question solved and share any other experiences you faced during Jenkins implementation.

Comment: I am new to this platform. How do I mark the question as solved? THanks!

Comment: my bad...:P
Actually U have already marked your question as solved by accepting my answer as solution. So you don't need to do anything now.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Possible...See this 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated above, follow: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs
Then I started getting this ugly error: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14107
If you face this problem as well, replace the current jenkins.war file with one from version 1.466. That is the one that worked for me. Before I replaced the war file, I stopped the jenkins server by : /etc/init.d/jenkins -stop and then replaced the war file and then started the server: /etc/init.d/jenkins -start

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use an instance of Jenkins to replace your cron jobs entirely.

See:

- [Drop that cron; use Hudson instead](http://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/drop-cron-use-hudson-instead)
- [Replace Local Cron With Jenkins](http://www.panozzaj.com/blog/2014/05/02/replace-local-cron-with-jenkins/)